# How can types represent both sets and propositions in Lambda calculus?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, type-theory

There is an interpretation of Lambda calculus that views a derivable statement $\Gamma \vdash x : A$ as the proposition $A$ with $x$ as "proof" of $A$.

However, there is another interpretation in which $\Gamma \vdash x : A$ is interpreted as the statement $x \in A$.

I have made my most important questions bold, but they can all be summarized with the question: **How do these two interpretations relate to each-other?**

Lets say $A$ is the type $\texttt {nat}$ for natural numbers. Its easy to see how $\Gamma \vdash 3 : \texttt{nat}$ could be interpreted as the statement $3 \in \mathbb{N}$, but how could it be interpreted as a proposition?

**How is $\texttt{nat}$ a proposition in and of itself? And furthermore, how is $3$ a "proof" of $\texttt{nat}$?**

**Is $\texttt{nat}$ equivalent to the proposition "$\mathbb{N}$ is non empty", and similarly, is producing an example of a member of $\mathbb{N}$, such as $3$, the "proof" of that proposition?**

If not, how is my thinking incorrect? 
If so, are there other interpretations of $\texttt{nat}$ as a proposition?

Looking at this from the other direction, you could have a $\Pi$-type in $\lambda P$ such as $\Pi x : \texttt{nat}\ .\ P$ where $P$ is the predicate "$P(x) = x$ is a natural number"

**How could the proposition $P[x := y]$ (i.e. "$y$ is a natural number") be interpreted as a set?** What is $P[x := y]$ a set *of*? Is it a set of proofs? That doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

---

**Edit for clarification:** It's important to note that, as far as I understand it, in lambda calculus, the predicate $P(x)$ is not in and of itself a set, it is a *family* of sets. Again, $P(x)$ is represented by a $\Pi$-type, *not* a type.

As far as I understand it, the predicate $P(x)$ would be written $\Pi x : \texttt{nat}\ .\ P $, which represents "$\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, P(x)$" which is typed as $\texttt{nat} \to *$. It is not until we apply a specific value to $P(x)$, i.e. $(\Pi x : \texttt{nat} . P) 3 \to_\beta P[x := 3]$, that it becomes typed as $*$, and is therefore an actual type (a.k.a. set).

So "$x$ is a natural number" would make sense as a set (the set of all natural numbers), but this is not how it is interpreted. Instead, "$x$ is a natural number" is a family of sets, and a specific instance of it (e.g. "3 is a natural number") is a set. How can something be a member of the set "3 is a natural number"? What does that even mean?

This is what is mostly confusing me in the second example mentioned above.

Comment: Something like $t:T$ is not a term of type theory. You can't write something like $(t:T)\lor(t:T')$. As such, there is no way of writing a proposition "$x$ has type $T$". If you were thinking of $P$ as something like $x:\mathtt{nat}$ that doesn't work (i.e. isn't a well-formed term) and also wouldn't really make sense anyway. If you have something else in mind, you should write the actual term you intend.

Comment: Generally, set theory and type theory look at the world very differently. In many cases, it is *not* possible to interpret types as sets in a straightforward way. Regardless, the closer analogue of a type in traditional mathematics would be a *sort* in (multi-sorted, first-order) logic. A type theory isn't a first-order theory like set theory, but rather it's a different logic. (You *can* make a higher-order logic where the individuals are typed lambda terms, but this is not the way type theory is used that leads to the propositions-as-types correspondence.)

Comment: You seem to be confusing the idea that types can be viewed as propositions with the idea that they interpret *a specific proposition*. "Is $\mathtt{nat}$ equivalent to the proposition '$\mathbb{N}$ is non empty'" - there is no unique proposition that $\mathtt{nat}$ "corresponds to"; from a propositions-as-types perspective, *it can be used as* any true proposition. And from a propositions-as-types perspective, one would never have an "$x$ is a natural number" predicate on $\mathtt{nat}$; $x:\mathtt{nat}$ already says that.

Comment: @DerekElkins "If you were thinking of  as something like : that doesn't work" 

You are correct. I wasn't thinking of it like that, but I suppose that would be how that statement would be naturally encoded in $\lambda$ calculus. The example in my book was $P(x) = x\text{  is prime}$. I am still new to Lambda calculus, so I don't know how this would be encoded. But hopefully you can understand why I am still not satisfied. There must exist some predicate $P(x)$ representable as a $\Pi$-type, otherwise this interpretation wouldn't exist.

Comment: @DerekElkins

"In many cases, it is not possible to interpret types as sets in a straightforward way" 

Why not? It seems like equivalence classes based on beta reduction is a pretty straightforward and general way to generate sets. I would think one could always see a type as a set of equivalence classes made using beta equivalence.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I am sure this is somewhat true, but I my guess was that the amount of *useful* interpretations would be relatively small in most cases.

Comment: Unless you can put a finer point on what you mean by "useful", I would say you're wrong. As a proposition, the type $\mathtt{nat}$ is logically equivalent to the singleton type $\mathbf{1}$, so its structure is basically no kind of constraint.

Comment: A term $t$ with a free variable $x$ is just represented by $t$, though it will only make sense in when $\Gamma$ contains $x$. We can have a function that produces types, call it $P$, then $P:\mathtt{nat}\to *$, say. $P(x):*$ when $x:\mathtt{nat}$. $\Pi x:\mathtt{nat}.P(x)$ is also a type so has type $*$, not $\mathtt{nat}\to *$. $\Pi$ is not $\lambda$. $(\Pi x:\mathtt{nat}.P(x))(3)$ isn't a well-formed term; it makes no more sense than $(\forall x.P(x))(3)$ would. Lambda abstractions are values of $\Pi$ types, e.g. $(\lambda x:A.f(x)):\Pi x:A.B(x))$ assuming $f$ has an appropriate type.

Comment: @DerekElkins Ah yes, it looks like I got confused. You're right that $\Pi x : \texttt{nat} . P(x))(3)$ isn't well formed and also that the type of  $\Pi$-term is $*$ not $\texttt{nat} \to *$. I actually think that clears up a lot of my confusion. So a $Pi$-type _is_ a proper type and thus can be thought of as a set in a way. 

However, there is still the question of how one would interpret $P(x)[x := 3]$ as both a proposition and a set (the proposition would be P(3)). If there truly isn't an intuitive interpretation of this as a set I can accept that. But I can't shake the feeling there is.

Comment: @DerekElkins Regardless, if you put the above in an answer and explain whether or not P(x)[x := 3] has an intuitive interpretation as a set I will accept it.

Comment: The most natural understanding of viewing types as propositions, which I assume your source was referring to, will be in the sense of the **Curry-Howard correspondence**. Searching for that keyword will give you plenty results; here are some concise overviews: Ch. 3.3 in https://uni-tuebingen.de/index.php?eID=tx_securedownloads&p=30440&u=0&g=0&t=1566660451&hash=9226b0dfa47f6acbd25bddc48ad0b6245017154b&file=/fileadmin/Uni_Tuebingen/Fakultaeten/InfoKogni/WSI/LS/piecha/teaching/lambda1718.pdf, and https://www.seas.harvard.edu/courses/cs152/2015sp/lectures/lec15-curryhoward.pdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do these two interpretations relate to each-other?

Going in the details would require a course in type theory, if you want to deepen your knowledge of the subject you should search reference on the Curry-Howard isomorphism.

An intuitive not too precise explanation of the relation between these interpretations is the following.

Generally to every proposition (not a predicate) can be associated a set: the set of its proofs.

This association has the property that it turns connectives into type formers: if we let $A$ be a proposition and denote with $[A]$ the associated set then we have that $[A \land B]=[A]\times[B]$, $[A \lor B]=[A] \amalg [B]$ and $[A \to B]=[A]\to[B]$.

There is more: the inference rules, that can be regarded as operations between proofs, correspond to special operations of the corresponding types.
As an example the inference rules

1. if $p$ is a proof of $A \land B$ then there is a proof $\pi_A(p)$ of the proposition $A$
2. if $p$ is a proof of $A \land B$ then there is a proof $\pi_B(p)$ of the proposition $B$

become the canonical projections $\pi_{[A]} \colon A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_{[B]} \colon A \times B \to B$.

The interesting point is that these sets corresponding to propositions are those *freely generated* by a set of variables and closing for certain operations (the so called constructors).

So you get this correspondence between the propositions of propositional logic (and relative proofs) and these sets (and their elements), this correspondence turns out to be bijective.

This correspondence can be extended to include predicates by introducing family of sets (i.e. set-valued functions).

This brings us to the next question.

> How could the proposition $P[x:=y]$ (i.e. "$y$ is a natural number") be interpreted as a set?

Predicates are not interpreted as sets, since they are not propositions.

A predicate is a family of propositions indexed by its possible arguments: 
a predicate $P(x)$ is a function that to every value $a$ (that can be assigned to $x$) associates the proposition $P(a)$.

If you get that, it should be obvious that a predicate should be interpreted not as a set but as a family of sets: i.e. a function sending every value of its argument into a set.

If $P(x)$ is a predicate, its interpretation is the function/family $[P(x)]$ defined by the equation
$$[P(x)](a) = \text{ the set of proofs of } P(a)$$
that is a set-valued function.

> How is nat a proposition in and of itself? And furthermore, how is 3 a "proof" of nat?
>   Is nat equivalent to the proposition "N is non empty", and similarly, is producing an example of a member of N, such as 3, the "proof" of that proposition?

To answer this question one should first specify what is the type system and the logic you are considering here.

The point here is that $\mathbf{nat}$ is a simple type, so it should correspond to a proposition in some logic. The problem is that it does not correspond to any proposition of any common used logic system.

For instance there is no proposition in the propositional logic that correspond to it. That is because $\mathbf{nat}$ does not belong to simply typed lambda calculus (STLC), it belongs to an *STLC with natural numbers* (an extension of STLC).

You could extend the propositional logic in a way to give a proposition corresponding to $\mathbf{nat}$. This would be an extension of propositional logic with a new constant proposition ($\mathbf{nat}$) with the following inference rules:

- there is a proof of $\mathbf{nat}$ named $0$
- is $n$ is a proof of $\mathbf{nat}$ then there is also another proof of $\mathbf{nat}$ named $n+1$
- if $p$ is a proof of $A$ and if $g$ is a proof of $A \to A$ then there is a proof of $\mathbf{nat}\to A$.

Such logic would not have really useful applications, since usually when applying logic we are interested in finding one proof for a  proposition, we do not necessarily need more proof, especially if the new proofs are more complex than the one we already have.

Hope this helps.

P.s. note that the type $\prod x\colon \mathbf{nat}. P(x)$ does not have type $\mathbf{nat} \to *$ but it has type $*$, in the very same way as $\forall x \in \mathbb N. P(x)$ is a proposition not a depending-predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to wade into this question in the hopes that it helps at least a little, or that it incites a real type theorist to write a better answer.

Forget about dependent types for a moment, and consider simple types. The first question you should ask is, if we are interpreting types as sets, what syntactic things should be interpreted as elements of those sets? Surely, the *closed terms* should qualify, if nothing else. We can see this intuition at work in the naive interpretation of the simple type $\mathtt{nat}$; $0$, $s0$, $s(s0)$, etc. are all naturally interpreted as the obvious natural numbers when we interpret $\mathtt{nat}$ as the set $\mathbb{N}$. Certain type theories resist interpretation of types as sets and terms as functions (particularly the ones with enough polymorphism), but types are always set-like in the sense that talk of closed terms, and of possible pluralities of closed terms, always makes sense.

How are simple types like propositions? Only in that if you interpret the sentences of your propositional logic as types in an appropriate way, a proposition is (intuitionistically) provable exactly when the corresponding type has a closed term. That's really it. Being a proposition isn't something types do intrinsically; rather types are amenable enough to a certain kind of interpretation that we can use types to reason correctly about propositions *as if* one were the other.

The generalization to dependent types is a bit more complicated in technical details, but the idea is the same. If we have a type theory with a dependent family $R:A\to A\to *$ and a constant $\mathsf{sym}:\Pi x,y:A.R(x,y)\to R(y,x)$, then we can use this type theory to interpret the (intuitionistic) first order theory of symmetric relations. If care is taken, we can use the fact that we've derived certain closed terms as evidence that certain theorems are true. In this sense we can again treat types as propositions. But if the type theory (and definition of $R$) has enough going on, there may very well be other closed terms of $\Pi x,y:A.R(x,y)\to R(y,x)$, or closed terms $a,b:A$ for which $R(a,b)$ has closed terms (this happens often if $R$ is an equality type in homotopy type theory, for example).

The thing to keep in mind is that you're going to confuse yourself if you ask "If $P(n)$ is a type family that means [whatever], do I interpret it as a set?" This has only the generic answer "because it's a type and in principle can have terms, which might be interpretable as elements of a set"; to see whether there actually are closed terms and what those might be (i.e. what might be "in that set"), too much depends on details. What type theory are we talking about? What, specifically, is $P(n)$, and what does the theory prove about it that makes it a good formalization of [whatever]? Unless you answer these, it's impossible to give you a specific set-like interpretation of an arbitrary logical predicate.